# Rename(/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: magento2, composer

I tried to run the composer self-update method and I'm getting this error message and I'm not sure where to start to fix this issue:

rename(/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956424/permission-denied-for-composer-in-usr-local-bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permission to update the plesk version of composer manually but it also should not be necessary:

> Plesk installs the updates for Composer once a week

[Source](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/administrator-guide/website-management/websites-and-domains/web-applications/managing-php-project-dependencies-with-composer.74969/)

If you need the latest version *now*, I recommend to install it in the project or in your home directory. For example:

- Download `composer.phar` from https://getcomposer.org
- Save it as `~/bin/composer`
- Use `composer` (or `~/bin/composer` if `~/bin` is not in your PATH) instead of `composer.phar` from Plesk

With this instance, you also can use `selfupdate`.